# MYSQL SELECT AND COUNT MULTIPLE ROWS BY MONTH

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the calculated result, how many were sold in January, February from one query.

`$query = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tableName WHERE status='sold' AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) = '$year' AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) = '1',  status='sold' AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) = '$year' AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) = '2'";

Comment: Have you tried using the `GROUP BY` expression?

Comment: Can you give me an example as an answer?

Comment: You can check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html to see how `GROUP BY` works, there are a lot of examples.

Comment: This forum is not for giving tutorials and pushing for learning, I asked someone if they had a similar problem and I need an answer to my question, I do not need a link where I will have to spend hours figuring out how to mark them all together. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you do not want to spend hours to learn and to find the best solution for a problem then maybe software development is not the best option for your career. Although I provided you an answer, I back up the comment of @Progman. Read the documentation and try to find a solution, don't ask others to do the work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to compute [aggregate values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html) you have to use [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `date`) AS year_month, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM tableName
WHERE `status` = 'sold'
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `date`)
```

Keep in mind that, because of the function [`EXTRACT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) used in the `GROUP BY` clause, MySQL cannot use an index to optimize the processing of the `GROUP BY` and, if the `WHERE` condition selects a large number of rows the query will be slow.